# Fitch Style Deduction in Non-Logic Classes

Tags: undergraduate-education, mathematical-pedagogy, proofs

Has anyone experimented with using [Fitch-style](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitch_notation) proofs as a teaching aid in courses outside of logic specifically and if so, how was the technique received by students?

Comment: I assume you're looking for cases that explicitly make use of levels of indentation?

Comment: It is a good idea, but you must really teach it well. Ideally, you should also make sure *you* can actually *do real mathematics* with it, otherwise many students will simply throw it away later because they cannot do more than toy proofs. You can take a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684204/21820) for a full-fledged Fitch-style foundational system that is actually practical in this sense.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I am writing a discrete math textbook which uses Fitch style proofs.

It has been well received so far.  I want to do a study to see if the students are better at comprehending and constructing proofs in followup courses if they have learned this style of natural deduction in their Discrete math class.

https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/19pXwLTowCwz1frNnVFNk0_v7KknxqXyJ